# Pandas/Python: Find missing values in time series, insert a new time stamp and a nan value for missing values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, series

I create the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'T': [1, 2, 4, 15], 'H': [3, 4, 6, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=['10.09.2018  13:15:00','10.09.2018  13:30:00', '10.09.2018  14:00:00', '10.09.2018  22:00:00'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

And get the following result.

```
Out[30]: 
                      T  H
2018-10-09 13:15:00   1  3
2018-10-09 13:30:00   2  4
2018-10-09 14:00:00   4  6
2018-10-09 22:00:00  15  8
```

As you can see there is one value missing at 13:45:00 and a lot values between 14:00 and 22:00.

Is there a way to automatically find the missing values, insert a row with the missing time stamp and nan values for the missing time ?

I want to achieve this:

```
Out[30]: 
                      T  H
2018-10-09 13:15:00   1  3
2018-10-09 13:30:00   2  4
2018-10-09 13:45:00  nan nan
2018-10-09 14:00:00   4  6
2018-10-09 14:15:00  nan nan
...
2018-10-09 21:45:00  nan nan
2018-10-09 22:00:00  15  8
```

Comment: `df.resample("900S").sum()`?

Comment: Use `df.asfreq('15T')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second dataframe with the correct timestep as index and join it with the original data. The following code worked in my case

```
# your code
import pandas as pd

d = {'T': [1, 2, 4, 15], 'H': [3, 4, 6, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=['10.09.2018  13:15:00','10.09.2018  13:30:00', '10.09.2018  14:00:00', '10.09.2018  22:00:00'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# generate second dataframe with needed index
timerange = pd.date_range('10.09.2018  13:15:00', periods=40, freq='15min')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=timerange)

# join the original dataframe with the new one
newdf = df.join(df2, how='outer')
```